# How can I fetch the existing table data in aportlet

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I am trying to create the user by site admin so I have created a portlet which has basic user details form and in the action class I called the `UserLocalServiceUtil.adduser()`. Now the values are inserting into the DB in `USER_`. Now I want to display the list of created users by only site admin how can I do that? I have the following queries.

1) How can I fetch the values from `USER_` in my portlet. Do I need to create the service builder OR are there API methods to fetch the values from the `USER_` table?

2) I want to display only the users list which is created by site admin in my portlet. I don't want to display the whole company list of users. So How can I achieve this?

Suggest me any references or guidelines to do this.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1 :

http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserLocalServiceUtil.html#getUsers(int, int)

This might help you. You don't need service builder for that. Just create a simple Liferay MVC portlet and call the relevant methods.

for Q2 : I don't think this would be possible by API methods. What you can do is to set an expando variable for user at time of creation by site-admin. And @ time of fetching users, you can cross-check the value of that field manually.

EDIT :

One more point for suggestion : Never create user with **Site-Admin** role for user creation. This role is supposed to manage site & user assignment to the site. You can use more appropriate role i.e. **Org-Admin** rather than site-Admin.

> How to set an expando variable while adding the user?

Liferay provides Expando API interface, which you can use while creation of user in your portlet. refer following links [Developing with Expando](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+with+Expando), [Liferay Expando API](http://proliferay.com/liferay-expando-api/)

I hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: No issues for the features. But its just to follow the standards, I guess. Hope you like the answer. Mark it as answer, if you like. Up vote would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure Definitely I will accept your answer. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am not clear how does Expando helps to my requirement. Can you please explain me your scenario.

Comment: Create custom attrb for user from LR control panel (e.g. CreatedbyID or createdByName). After user creation Method from your Portlet, set this custom attrb value from your code.

Comment: So you mean to say If I use Expando, Can it be possile to add additional column(CreatedByID) in USER_ table. and fetch the values based on that column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74026/discussion-between-aston-and-vinod).